# Is there a GUI tool to organize 'open with' entries?

Tags: file-manager, .desktop

As there are several places where a file manager can get its entries for the context menus 'open-with' list, and some of these entries are not too easy to identify by hand, I asked myself if there is a program to organize these entries, e.g. showing an accumulated list for each file type, with all properties of the according `.desktop` files and the possibility to edit, add or remove some entries. I am mostly curious to find a solution for programs which do not focus on the KDE or Gnome universe (which they may do additionally), but which use the broader approaches via `mimeapps.list` `…share/applications/….desktop`, etc.

Any nice program I have overseen?

Comment: KDE > Settings > Applications > File associations

Comment: There need to be some specifics listed... like which Desktop... I generally run `openbox` and my MIME "open with" preferences are contained in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` ... I think Gnome has a bunch of `gsettings` lists somewhere and KDE is going to be different as well.